# Double would in conditonal sentences

Tags: conditional-constructions

I know I can say

> 1. I would write a letter if I **wanted** my message to be warm and personal.

But is it grammatical to say

> 2. I would write a letter if I **would like** to be warm and personal.

I'm confused because this is conditional statement so there should be no **would** after if (in general) but on the other hand **I would like** has different meaning than I like/liked.

I'd like to make sure if both sentences are correct.

Thanks

Comment: The conditional mood, like the subjunctive, requires word conjugations that are similar to the past tense.  You can say:  If **I wanted** or if **I had wanted** but not *if I would like*.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be gramattical, I'm not certain, but worse, it's awkward. Another way to rephrase it would be

> I would write a letter if I meant for my message to be warm and personal.